# How should we define mutli-dimensional structs inside julia?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to define matrix-like structures. How should I define them? For example defining a matrix like this:

```
struct Mat
    r11::Float64
    r12::Float64
    r21::Float64
    r22::Float64
end
```

But when the matrix is big, it can't be written like that. How should I define multi-dimensional matrices to be memory efficient and fast when added, subtracted, etc.

Comment: Just use a real `Matrix`?  Or have a field that's a `Matrix` and [subtype `AbstractArray`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array-1)?

Comment: A structure defined like a matrix.

Comment: Then do the latter.  Check out that link and https://github.com/JuliaArrays/ for inspiration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to use the already existing [`StaticArrays`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl). That's a high-quality, well-maintained package that implements Matrix-like structs.

`StaticArrays` uses an `NTuple` as the underlying data, which means it can vary in length. Its type definition is something like this:

```
struct StaticMatrix{T, R, C, N}
    data::NTuple{N, T}
end
```

Operations on static arrays are extremely efficient. For example:

```
julia> using StaticArrays

julia> a = SMatrix{2,2}(rand(4));

julia> code_native(+, Tuple{typeof(a), typeof(a)}, debuginfo=:none)
    .text
    vmovupd (%rsi), %ymm0
    vaddpd  (%rdx), %ymm0, %ymm0
    vmovupd %ymm0, (%rdi)
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    vzeroupper
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```